# how to get the msg.sender contribution in eth

Tags: solidity, remix

I made a contract where a wallet can contribute eth.

If someone wants to get a refund, how can I use Solidity to see how much `msg.sender` contributed.

I searched but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding right, you've got a function to allow users to contribute, and another for refunding. I can think of two things you might be getting stuck on, so I'll try to explain both clearly.

#### 1) `msg.value`

Usually when contracts interact with ERC20 tokens, the contract itself will use something like `transferFrom` to make sure the correct amount of tokens are taken, and that they are delivered to the right address. ether doesn't have something like `transferFrom` currently, though that might change someday with account abstraction. Instead, the user interacting with the contract chooses how much ether they send along with the call to the function. If that's the case, you might be wondering how you know if they sent ether, or how much they sent.

If that's the case, I've got good news for you. Solidity has a variable called `msg.value` which stores how much wei was sent, the same way `msg.sender` shows which address called the contract.

#### 2) storing values

Once you know about `msg.value`, it's really as simple as storing the value in something like a mapping. If you do that, you'll have an internal accounting system for contributions, and can then access it to refund.

For example (**don't use this code**, this is only for illustration):

```
mapping(address => uint256) public contributions;

function contribute() external payable {
  contributions[msg.sender] += msg.value;
}

function refund() external {
  address user = msg.sender;
  user.call{value: contributions[user]}("");
}
```

#### 3) gotchas

You might notice that this code will only keep track of ether sent to the `contribute` function. If someone sends ether to the contract without calling `contribute`, it won't be tracked. If this is a concern, you can use a fallback either to account or to revert.

Comment: Adding another ⚠️ warning to make the point not to use the code in the answer since a user will be able to extract funds from other users.